# DNS resolve to CNAME which is not my website. Can someone explain?

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a website at www.grokit.ca hosted on google app engine. If I issue the following command:

`nslookup -query=any -debug www.grokit.ca`

... I get the following output:

```
$ nslookup -query=any -debug www.grokit.ca
Server:         X.Y.Z.12
Address:        X.Y.Z.12#53

------------
    QUESTIONS:
        www.grokit.ca, type = ANY, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    ->  www.grokit.ca
        canonical name = ghs.googlehosted.com.
        ttl = 400
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ADDITIONAL RECORDS:
------------
Non-authoritative answer:
www.grokit.ca   canonical name = ghs.googlehosted.com.
```

Same with dig: `dig www.grokit.ca`:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.6 <<>> www.grokit.ca
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 34283
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4000
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.grokit.ca.                 IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.grokit.ca.          865     IN      CNAME   ghs.googlehosted.com.
ghs.googlehosted.com.   214     IN      A       74.125.28.121

;; Query time: 55 msec
;; SERVER: X.Y.Z.12#53(X.Y.Z.12)
;; WHEN: Fri Dec 11 17:53:03 PST 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 92
```

So basically I get it, my domain is CNAME (~alias), which is linked to ghs.googlehosted.com, which is at IP address 74.125.28.121. However, if I point the browser to 74.125.28.121, this is just a default google website:

[image]
So my question is, **where is the rest of the DNS lookup**? How does the browser know where to issue the GET given that if it uses the IP resolved by DNS it will get a 404 (going to the website on a web browser from www.grokit.ca does work).